# Back button on actionbar closes entire app instead of going back to previous activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a beginner in android studio and I've been having a issue for a while now. In my actionbar the back button closes the entire app instead of going to the previous activity ! here is my code

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_brochures__view2);

    if(getSupportActionBar()!=null)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            onBackPressed();

            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is Android Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".Brochures_View2"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"

        android:parentActivityName=".Brochures_Menu"/>
```

So I did some research and found out that it has something to do with Android launchmode but when I tried all possible choices , the back/up button still closes the whole app. I've tried removing onbackpressed and putting finish() but no use.

thank you

Comment: What is `navigateUpFromSameTask` and how are you starting this Activity?

Comment: navigateUpFromSameTask() finishes the current activity and starts (or resumes) the appropriate parent activity in this case the previous activity that i specified in the manifest.

Comment: onBackpressed() doesn't do anything ; I've tried placing it in different parts of the code but the issue is very stubborn ; app keeps closing .

Comment: remove "launchMode" from manifest file

Comment: I just tried removing launchMode , but no use

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is override onBackPressed and trigger the activity you want when that button is pressed. It allows you to control the flow of the app not depending on the activity stack.

Comment: @ Lenin How do I do that ? I already have a override on the top of the function/method that has the onBackPressed

Comment: You only have to override the method and start a new activity. If you want to go to the previous activity (home) just start it again.

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent)

Answer (score 0):

Alright i finally figured it out. The issue was finish() ; ya i had finish() before i started all my activities (Intent) . So from what i understand is that finish() pops the activity from the stack therefore making the stack empty . So in my case there was nothing on the stack because i called finish() before i started any intent/activity leaving the app with no other choice but to exit. It makes sense now.